# How to prevent entity of one type from being saved if entity of another type already exists

Tags: spring, jpa, concurrency, spring-transactions

I have an entity of type `EntityA` that I only want to persist (specifically insert) in the database if an entity of a type `EntityB` does not already exist in the database. `EntityA` has a property that can be used to check if `EntityB` exists.

I've tried to check that `EntityB` does not already exist prior to inserting `EntityA`:

```
@Transactional
public void saveEntityAIfEntityBNotExist(EntityA a) {

    if (entityBRepository.existsByCommonStringProp(a.getCommonStringProp())) {
        throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("one or more entityBs already exist.");
    }

    entityARepository.save(a);
}
```

The problem with this code is that some other user may have saved and committed an `EntityB` with the common string prop in between the exists check and the save.

The desired result would be for the transaction to rollback if upon commit `EntityB` now exists. The same behavior applies when saving `EntityB` (i.e. it needs to check if `EntityA` exists upon commit). How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can use @UniqueConstraint on CommonStringProp column

Comment: `@UniqueConstraint` is a class level annotation that applies to a given entity. I have two entities. Not sure how it would help here. Could you please provide more detail? Thanks.

Comment: @James Is the converse also true?  I.e., if there's an Entity A already committed, do you need to prevent future Entity Bs with the same common prop to be inserted?  If so, one approach is to create a third table, with the common prop as a unique constraint.  Whenever A or B is being inserted, they also need to commit to this third table.  This will ensure there's only either A or B row for the common prop, but not both.

Comment: @peekay Yes. The converse is also true. That seems like a workable approach. Thanks.